# Find the value of $1440a^2b^2c^2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Given $$4a^2+9b^2+16c^2+\frac{1}{9a^2}+\frac{1}{16b^2}+\frac{1}{25c^2}=\frac{133}{30}$$ Find the value of:$$1440a^2b^2c^2$$ (where a,b and c are non-zero real numbers)**

I could not think of any approach.

What I can think most probably is that $a^3+b^3+c^3=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)$ will be used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the inequality $\frac{p+q}{2} \ge \sqrt{pq}$ we may show that

$$ 4a^2+\frac{1}{9a^2} +9b^2 + \frac{1}{16b^2} + 16c^2 + \frac{1}{25c^2} \ge 2\cdot (\frac 2 3 + \frac 3 4 + \frac 4 5) = \frac{133}{30} $$

However, the necessary and sufficient condition that the equality holds is that $4a^2=\frac{1}{9a^2} $, $9b^2 = \frac{1}{16b^2} $ and $16c^2 = \frac{1}{25c^2} $ hold simultaneously. Once the values $a^2$, $b^2$, and $c^2$ are solved, it is easy to calculate the desired final result.

Answer (score 1):

An alternate way to find the value of $$1440a^2b^2c^2$$ would be to use the identity $(a-b)^2$.

$$4a^2+\frac{1}{9a^2}-2(2a×\frac{1}{3a})+9b^2+\frac{1}{16b^2}-2(3b×\frac{1}{4b})+16c^2+\frac{1}{25c^2}-2(4c×\frac{1}{5c})=\frac{133}{30}-\frac{4}{3}-\frac{6}{4}-\frac{8}{5}=\frac{133}{30}-\frac{133}{30}=0$$

$(2a-\frac{1}{3a})^2+(3b-\frac{1}{4b})^2+(4c-\frac{1}{5c})^2=0$

As, All the terms are squared,

$2a=\frac{1}{3a},3b=\frac{1}{4b}, 4c=\frac{1}{5c}$

That gives us,

$6a^2=1,12b^2=1,20c^2=1$

Multiplying all these we get $$1440a^2b^2c^2=1$$